# c++ trying to change local variable in function

Tags: c++, function

im learning functions and I have been trying to call my last value for total from my function (so the total that is labeled "total so far") when going through the for loop (which print out 36 when using 8 as the test number) to print out 36 again in my main function at "your total is"

I understand it is not printing out 36 because in the function I am treating total as a local variable and I think I need to use it as a global or static but I'm not sure

also when I did attempt to make it a static I'm not sure I did it right I wrote static in front of both my total variables when defining them

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int count);

int main()
{
    int count;
    double num, total;

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (count = 1; count <=num;  count = count + 1)
    {
        sum(count);
    }

    cout << "Your total is: " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}

int sum(int count)
{
    double total;
    total = total + count;
    cout << "Current number: " << count << endl;
    cout << "Total so far: " << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why not returning `total`? you already declared your function as `int`. return `total` from your function and store it in `total` that you defined in your main, or you can pass `total` as reference to your `sum` function and remove declaration of total in `sum`.

Comment: @Hamed I actually have tried return total; in my function it still returns 0 for your total is

Comment: @GinaCucchiara Because you are not assigning the return value of `sum()` to the `total` variable in `main()`

Comment: As I told, You need to assign it's return value to the `total` you declared in your main. like this `total += sum(count);`. but remember, you need to initialize your `total` first, like this `double total = 0.0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`total` is uninitialized in both `main()` and `sum()`, so any results you get are indeterminate.

And indeed, `total` inside of `sum()` is local to `sum()`, and `total` in `main()` is local to `main()`.  Any changes `sum()` makes to its own `total` do not affect the `total` in `main()`.

You should change `sum()` to take `total` from `main()` as an input parameter passed by pointer/reference so that `sum()` can modify its value:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sum(double &total, int count);

int main()
{
    int count, num;
    double total = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (count = 1; count <= num; ++count)
    {
        sum(total, count);
    }

    cout << "Your total is: " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}

void sum(double &total, int count)
{
    total += count;
    cout << "Current number: " << count << endl;
    cout << "Total so far: " << total << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/KlId0C)

Answer (score 1):

`total` in `main()` and `total` in `sum()` are different variables for they have different block scope.

```
int sum(int count) {
   // such a silly pass-through implementation if you want to calculate "total"
   // do something with count
   return count;
}
// in main
double total = 0;
total += sum(count);
```

Comment: I think you mean `return count`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, oh yeah, was not finished modifying.